# How to search a trinary tree?

Tags: search, tree, scheme, racket

I just started learning scheme. I'm trying to make a procedure to look for an item in a trinary tree. It returns true if it is found.

Here is what I got so far:

```
(define nullnode '())
(define leaf (lambda (x) (eqv? '() x) nullnode (list x nullnode nullnode nullnode)))
(define tritree (list 9 (leaf 1) (leaf 2) (leaf 3))) 
; (display tritree) => (9 (1 () () ()) (2 () () ()) (3 () () ()))

(define lookup
  (lambda (tr x)
    (or  (eqv? x (car tr))
       (and (list? (cdr tr)) (lookup (cadr tr) x)))))
```

I want to get out of (leaf 1) and go through (leaf 2). How can I do that?

Is there a better way to define my lookup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a straightforward implementation of how to search in a tree, it's just that this time we have three possible subtrees:

```
(define lookup
  (lambda (tr x)
    (cond ((null? tr) #f)
          ((equal? (first tr) x) #t) ; don't use eqv?, equal? is more general
          (else
           (or (lookup (second tr) x)
               (lookup (third  tr) x)
               (lookup (fourth tr) x))))))
```

Alternatively, without using `cond` (and a bit closer to what you had in mind):

```
(define lookup
  (lambda (tr x)
    (and (not (null? tr))
         (or (equal? (first  tr) x)
             (lookup (second tr) x)
             (lookup (third  tr) x)
             (lookup (fourth tr) x)))))
```

And *do* notice that your implementation of `leaf` is incorrect, for the above to work you'll have to fix it first:

```
(define leaf 
  (lambda (x)
    (if (null? x)
        nullnode
        (list x nullnode nullnode nullnode))))
```

It works as expected with the sample input:

```
(lookup tritree 3)
=> #t
(lookup tritree 5)
=> #f
```